# How to show this limit exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know the limit is 0, but how would I prove the limit? $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} {\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}}$$

Answer (score 1):

As 
\begin{align*}
x^4+y^6 = \frac{1}{2} x^4 + \frac{1}{2} x^4 + y^6 \geq \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}x^{8/3}y^2,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}\Big| \leq \frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}|x|^{1/3} \rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: @A15234: It is true no matter x and y are positive or negative, as the powers for terms in the denominators have a even component (i.e., 2, 4, 6, or 8, and then you can write x as |x| etc.), while for the numerator, we can take the absolute.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use Polar coordinates.

You can do this because the $|r|$ (where $r$ is the radius) and $|(x,y)|$ are equivalent.